# If a journey's entry source is a DE, and every record is reviewed when automation runs, is contact removed from the DE removed from the journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey that runs with a pretty simple set of criteria for populating the data extension (communication owner = x). Currently I have a journey running where someone on our data team put in the incorrect communication owner. We have gone ahead and updated the communication owner. The data extension is updated daily on an automation, and the automation review every record, not only updating for new ones. Given the criteria, to my knowledge, this contact is no longer populating in the data extension.

Excuse my ignorance, but will this contact now be removed from receiving future emails from this journey? Or is there another process I need to follow in order to remove them? Basically, if my automation and journey review every contact in the DE, does removing them from the DE remove them from the journey?

Answer (score 1):

A contact not present in entry Data Extension will not automatically be removed. This Data Extension only decides who is to enter a journey (given they also fulfill re-entry criteria + any additional entry filters).

If you want to ensure a contact exits a journey after entering, you need to work with Exit Criteria. You can connect a Data Extension to your contact model in Data Designer, and list all your contacts with their respective owners. If a contact no longer has owner = X, he will exit the journey. Exit criteria are evaluated when contact leaves any given wait step.

Comment: Is this able to be done once a journey has begun? We didn't anticipate this issue initially, so other exit criteria is already set up.

Comment: Yes, this can only be done by creating a new version